# Что можно сделать если в IIS SSL сертификат не работает, хотя локально работает?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient

Создал два проекта Web Api(back) и MVC(front). Web Api(back) опубликован в IIS, а MVC(front) запускаю локально. В проекте Web Api есть POST запрос в котором используется SSL сертификат. Между MVC(front) и Web Api(back) я общаюсь через GET/POST запросы. Сайт работает, проходит авторизацию и отображаются отчеты. Но если я вызываю с MVC(front) метод, который использует SSL сертификат в Web Api(back), то выходит ошибка: `One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)`.

А вот если я запускаю локально Web Api(back) на серваке и локально MVC(front) на серваке, и делаю запрос на тот же самый метод, но у меня проходит все без ошибки.

Вот код с Фронта

```
public string Identity(RequestClass<IdentificationModel> request)
        {            
            ResponseClass<decimal> response = new ResponseClass<decimal>();
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var httpResponse =
                        httpClient.PostAsync(_apiUrl + $"Identification", data).Result;
                string responseContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                
                return responseContent;
            }
        }
```

Вот код с Бэка

```
public decimal GetIdentification(IdentificationModel identification, int key)
    {
        try
        { 
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"cert\\hgg.p12");
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, _certPassword));

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _identityUrl + "iin=" + identification.IIN + "&vendor=" + _vendor))
            {
                string token = GetToken();
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-idempotency-key", "key:" + "hggKey-" + key);
                request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                //request.Content = new StringContent(identification.Photo);
                request.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(identification.Photo)));
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");

                var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                string data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data).result;
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetIdentification" + e.Message);
        }
    }
    public string GetToken()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "cert\\hgg.p12");
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, _certPassword));
        try
        {
            

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _tokenUrl))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic " + _token);
                    request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                    request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + _username + "&password=" + _password + "&scope=identkey");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).access_token;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("GetToken" + e.Message + path + " " +_certPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `see inner exception` - и что там в InnerException? `.Result` нельзя использовать - используйте `await`.

Comment: Можно использовать .Result

Comment: `.Result` является блокирующим поток, `await` - не блокирующим, то есть асинхронным. При вызове асинхронной операции с блокировкой текущего потока можно получить дедлок. Тогда перфразирую, в целом `.Result` для незавершенного `Task` использовать нельзя, но лично вам можно. `async/await` не кусается, [почитайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Вторая ваша ошибка, чтоо вы на каждый запрос спавните `HttpClient`, но согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1#examples) _HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._ А все это потому, что при большом числе запросов у вас могут закончиться сокеты. Но вам это тоже можно делать, я не возражаю, забудьте что я про ошибку говорил.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationPoolIdentity не имеет разрешение для хранилищ сертификата, поэтому в IIS он не работал